# Checkbox Issue in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I have a multiple checkbox in tableview cell and total number of cell 4,i want to select one checkbox at one time and all check box is unselect if i select any one of check box and also one button in table view cell button are also disable of other cell so how i implement this logic.[here i implement image check and uncheck logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eIMx.png)

```
func setupData(plansModel: [Plans], mainRowIndex: Int, selctedPlan: Int, isAllUnselected: Bool){
    self.plansModel = plansModel
    indexMain = mainRowIndex
    selectedPlanId = selctedPlan
    self.isAllUnselected = isAllUnselected
    self.changePlanBtn.isHidden = isAllUnselected
    
    priceTableView.reloadData()
}
```

i take this variable for data and manage checkbox

Comment: Can you explain your question by showing UI

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji754.png)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJxK.png)

You can do this Way!
Firts make a variable

```
var selectedIndex: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```

Second in tableview didselecte method add this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let previousSelectedIndex = selectedIndex
    selectedIndex = indexPath
    checkBoxTableView.reloadRows(at: [previousSelectedIndex, selectedIndex], with: .none)
}
```

third and last add this code in tableview cellForRow Method

```
if selectedIndex.row == indexPath.row {
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

I think your answer is solved.

This Was edited For realod only two row rather than whole tableview (this edit rafrence by [paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)).

Thank you [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) For helping!

Comment: Reloading the whole tableview rather than just the two affected rows is a bit excessive

Comment: Yeah This i true.